# Java println string not showing up in CMD

Tags: java, cmd, printing, javac, println

I am trying to execute the simple java application in CMD using javac but the outputs of System.out.println is not coming out.
Let me show you my code in my MyFirstProgram java file.

```
public class MyFirstProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      int number =10;
      System.out.println(number);
      System.out.println("Hello, World!");
      System.out.println("Strange");
   }
}
```

Also showing you the results when I executed javac in CMD.
I tried not only string but also integer variable in println but still doesn't show up anything. However, if the compile error log comes up when there is a source logic error so I don't think it's an source issue.

[ CMD Result ]

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\test>javac MyFirstProgram.java

{blank}
```

Let me share you my java jdk version for reference. I believe there is an issue in the jdk version or maybe my PC settings. Can anyone help me out on this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\test>java -version
java version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21.0.1+12-LTS-29)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.1+12-LTS-29, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Thank you.

Comment: That question has an easy and simple answer: *javac* compiles your program, but does not strat/execute it. Look in the directory if threre is a new file MyFirstprogram.*class*.

Comment: Just to remove all doubt, and echoing other comments, your command line should be `C:\Users\username\Documents\test>java MyFirstProgram`

Comment: @g00se iff the call has not been changed for java version "21. ...". They do lot of changes now, but little improvement (if you ask my opinion).

Comment: It hasn't afaik. It would be very alarming if `javac` now *runs* stuff too

Comment: @g00se I had some issues with *java -cp etc.*. Doesn't work like I remember it to do, took about an hour of internet research and try&error. Worse are all those *improvements* on the syntax. Lamda's screwed up eclipse (and I can't deny the feeling this was on purpose.)

Comment: I really don't understand why this poor fellow gets so much downvotes. Asking an easy question in all honesty isn't a sin, is it?

Comment: @GyroGearloose I can see it might be expecting an explicit classpath rather than the implicit current directory

Comment: @g00se "it might be expecting" ... exactly that, and even more I was referring to when I said in a previous comment: "They do lot of changes now, but little improvement (if you ask my opinion). "

Comment: No one has marked this as a duplicate, and as it a honest question, with no duplicates easily to be found, I upvote it to counter the lowly and, uncommented, downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javac is used to compile the java file not executing it
if you looked at same folder you will find your compiled java file

you can run it using java command and see output

Comment: Executed "java MyFirstProgram.java" and it worked. Thank you for all your support.